# $parent->addSalle($child) generate uneeded extra query

Tags: symfony, doctrine, symfony4

I'm currently optimizing doctrines queries, and noticed that doctrine generate extra queries on data it already got in the unit of work (UOW).

Yet, when I try to add/associate child objects to it's parent, Doctrine is querying to get all the childs (which are already in the UOW)

This is how I do it :

```
//Getting (root) Salle of the view
$salle=$salleRepository->findBy(array('isAccueil'=>true));

//Get '$salle' children
$salles=$salleRepository->findBy(array('salle'=>$salle));

//For each children of each `Salle` in $salle
foreach($salleRepository->findBy(array('salle'=>$salles)) as $child) {

    //Go through each parent
    foreach($salles as $parent) {

        //If parent id match child parent id
        if($parent->getId() == $child->getSalle()->getId()) {

            //Doctrine extra query happen here
            //Query for current parent's children
            $parent->addSalle($child);
        }
    }
}
```

As written in code comment, Doctrine query for current parent's children.
But those children already exists in the UOW, I did query for them on the first `foreach`.

Is there a way to reassociate children to parent so Doctrine won't do extra query?

Answer (score 2):

You're executing those two queries right at the beginning.

Doctrine's unit of work (UOW) is **not a result-cache**. You probably misunderstood that.

```php
// FIRST
$salles=$salleRepository->findBy(array('salle'=>$salle));

// SECOND
foreach($salleRepository->findBy(array('salle'=>$salles)) as $child) {
```

You should instead combine those two queries into a single query inside your repository.

Example:

```php
// tip: don't use assignments in loop definitions and conditional statements
$children = $salleRepository->findSalleBySallesSalle($salle);

$foreach ($children as $child) {
  // ..
}
```

Think about it like this:

What if the database changed between those 2 queries and you really wanted two different results?

Doctrine does let you configure a separate query- and result-cache but here you should just use a combined query.

Comment: Database changing meanwhile won't happen. It's just that kind of project. As for your suggestion. You code is basically what I'm doing already. I get the children on a seperate instance (except that I don't use a variable to store them). The problem here is not getting the children. My problem is that doctrine is doing uneeded extra query when I associate parent and children. If you're telling me that it will do it no matter what, then I will just loop in the twig view. My final goal is just to get a count of the children.

Comment: As I said - use one single combined query in a repository-method. Especially if your goal is just the count. You can get the count directly from SQL with Doctrine, too. Right now you're  explicitly asking Doctrine to perform two queries by calling `findBy*` twice.

Comment: If you're talking about the `$child->getSalle()` call creating an extra query upon being called: use the **eager loading** strategy instead of the default lazy-loading. But as you said you need just the count -> go for a single query.